# ClassNotFoundException while indexing data into elasticsearch org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedConsumer

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-camel, elasticsearch-rest-client

I am using below stack to index a data into Elasticsearch:

- **Elasticsearch 7.15.1**
- **Apache Camel 3.12.0**
- **Spring 5.3.12**
- **Spring Boot 2.5.6**

While indexing the data into Elasticsearch [7.15.1] I am getting **ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedConsumer**

please have a look on the detailed error below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedConsumer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[indexer-IPM-12.0.4-CP4D-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer$HighLevelClient.<init>(ElasticsearchProducer.java:347) ~[camel-elasticsearch-rest-3.12.0.jar:3.12.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer$HighLevelClient.<init>(ElasticsearchProducer.java:345) ~[camel-elasticsearch-rest-3.12.0.jar:3.12.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.process(ElasticsearchProducer.java:124) ~[camel-elasticsearch-rest-3.12.0.jar:3.12.0]
at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.12.0.jar:3.12.0]
... 11 more
```

I tried to lower the versions of all the above mentioned stack, but no luck.

Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959212/elasticsearch-resthighlevelclient-missing-transitive-dependencies)?

Comment: @Nexevis I already had a look to this question, mentioned dependencies like  elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client  are present in my pom.xml. but still i am facing the issue. 
But in addition to this i also have elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.1.jar in my pom.xml