# Apache Camel Elasticsearch endpoint failing with ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedConsumer

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, apache-camel

After recent spring boot version upgrade, While indexing data into Elasticsearch through camel, my  endpoint is failing.

> ```
>                                     Old version        New version
> Spring Boot:                           2.5.2              2.6.2
> camel-core:                            3.11.1             3.14.0
> camel-elasticsearch-rest-starter       3.11.1             3.14.0
> Elasticsearch:                         7.8.0              7.15.2
> ```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedConsumer
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer$HighLevelClient.<init>(ElasticsearchProducer.java:347) ~[camel-elasticsearch-rest-3.14.0.jar:3.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer$HighLevelClient.<init>(ElasticsearchProducer.java:345) ~[camel-elasticsearch-rest-3.14.0.jar:3.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.process(ElasticsearchProducer.java:124) ~[camel-elasticsearch-rest-3.14.0.jar:3.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
```

Tried below things but none of them helped.

- [Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient missing transitive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959212/elasticsearch-resthighlevelclient-missing-transitive-dependencies)
- Increased Apache Camel version from 3.11.1 to 3.14.0 to make it compatible with spring boot version.

One thing I observed is that, the aforementioned class CheckedConsumer has moved to different package between Elasticsearch version 7.8.0 and 7.15.2. I was assuming, increasing camel to 3.14.0 should resolve this issue, but it's still referring to old package.

```
Old package:  org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedConsumer
New package:  org.elasticsearch.core.CheckedConsumer
```

Comment: I do not have an answer.
It sounds like a bug that you can report to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html

one interestign point is that the java high level rest client is deprecated since 7.15.0 and should be replaced with Elastic search Java API client https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html

Comment: Hello, were you able to find a solution? I'm also getting a similar error when adding SpringBoot Actuator. [Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchRestHighLevelClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/core/CheckedConsumer]

Comment: @saavedrah No, I couldn't find any solution. I had to revert to older Elasticsearch version(7.8.0) in order for it to work again.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in class ElasticsearchProducer. In the inner class HighLevelClient there is code like:

```
super(restClient, client -> {}, Collections.emptyList());
```

The second parameter here has type org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedConsumer, this is why we get this error.
If you have access to sources of the library camel-elasticsearch-rest, you can create your own extentions of camel classes:

```
CustomElasticsearchProducer extends ElasticsearchProducer
CustomElasticsearchEndpoint extends ElasticsearchEndpoint
CustomElasticsearchComponent extends ElasticsearchComponent
```

In the class CustomElasticsearchComponent you should override the method createEndpoint:

```
    @Override
    protected Endpoint createEndpoint(String uri, String remaining, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
        ...
        return new CustomElasticsearchEndpoint(...);
    }
```

In the class CustomElasticsearchEndpoint you shold override the method createProducer:

```
@Override
public Producer createProducer() throws Exception {
    ...
    return new CustomElasticsearchProducer(this, configuration);
}
```

And finally, in the class CustomElasticsearchProducer you should override the method process: just copy here code from ElasticSearchProducer with private methods and inner class.
This is very huge solution, maybe we can fix it with AOP or something, but I dont know how.

I know it is late but maybe it will be helpful for someone